In android studio Jellyfish when I add the new activity into my existing project following error occurs
Following are error details:
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
I didn't try anything just add activity into the project

any soloutions??
